# Python - Undo script if script fails

Tags: python, scripting

Sometime when writing a python script I will run into an error such as syntax or some Exceptions. The script will partially execute, but not everything. This is frustrating because I have to manually undo what the script executed before I can run the script again. Is there a way that I can have the script undo what it has done if it fails. I want the script to only make permanent changes if it ran without error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could enable Undo support for your operator. Below

```
bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
```

add

```
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
```

But I wouldn't make the operator undo itself on errors, rather let the user do it if necessarily. However, your script shouldn't raise exceptions in the first place, but check in the operator's `poll()` classmethod, if all pre-conditions are met. Or let it `return {'CANCELLED'}` inside the `execute()` body before something is damaged.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your script in an operator. You will only need one undo step then. Just replace the main function of this (shortened) template from *Text Editor* -> *Python* -> *Operator Simple*

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    #your script here
    pass

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
try:
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
except Exception as e:
    print("something went wrong")
    #raise the exception again
    raise e
```

(See CoDeman's post). Using blender's undo system with [`bpy.ops.ed.undo`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.ed.html?highlight=undo#bpy.ops.ed.undo) is rather unreliable.

You may:

- check if requirements are met before performing your actions
- save some data with python and restore it if an error occured
- write a backup to disk and load it if an error occurred