# Crash when undoing a custom operator

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a tool to help me manage my hierarchy. I have this operator which creates an empty object, that i will use for parenting later on.
This works fine, but blender crashes when i undo this operator.

Steps to reproduce:

- Run this script
- Click on the "Create Empty" button
- Undo (ctrl + z)

This crashes blender with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

```
import bpy

class CreateEmptyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Create Empty"
    bl_idname = "wm.create_empty"

    def execute(self, context):
        parent = bpy.data.objects.new("Empty", None)
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(parent)
        return{'FINISHED'}

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("wm.create_empty")

bpy.utils.register_class(CreateEmptyOperator)
bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)
```

What can I do to avoid the crash?

Comment: You need to enable undo for your operator. Not the same question but the answer is the same : https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7066/86891 By the way, replace `bpy.context.collection.objects.link(parent)` by `context.collection.objects.link(parent)` (always use passed context when available)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the [Undo / Redo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html) system to work with a custom operator, you need to add `bl_options = {'UNDO'}` when defining the class.

Your script then becomes :

```
import bpy

class CreateEmptyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Create Empty"
    bl_idname = "wm.create_empty"
    bl_options = {'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        parent = bpy.data.objects.new("Empty", None)
        context.collection.objects.link(parent)  # Use the current context when available instead of bpy.context
        return {'FINISHED'}

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("wm.create_empty")

bpy.utils.register_class(CreateEmptyOperator)
bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)
```